# Accessing encrypted USB hard drive, which is attached to a commercial router, through Samba

Tags: encryption, samba

I am planning to do the following setup: I have a home router which has an USB port and a hard drive attached to it. I want to share all the contents of it through Samba (already done as the router has Samba built-in).

What I really want to do is to share the files encrypted. So that when I connect to my router through a Windows, Linux or Android device I can read and write to the hard drive and everything remains encrypted.

The point is that even that the Samba credentials would been compromised then the encryption is still another level of security.

As the router is a commercial one, I don't believe that I can manually configure its internal Samba.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I saw similar questions and answers on the Internet but they weren't specific enough. Eg. [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1273237/can-multiple-user-access-bitlocker-encrypted-hard-drive-via-router), but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: What's the make/model of the router?  You might be able to access the internal router OS and make changes.  But drive encryption and Samba are two different things.

Comment: You can always chnage the samba configuration it just might require you to SSH into the router in order to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypt a folder with [VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/), available for most platforms, including Winbdows, Linux, Mac OS X, even Raspberry Pi, [or a similar encryption application](https://alternativeto.net/software/veracrypt/).

[Note that VeraCrypt *can* be opened for sharing on a network, but there are options for read-only use (mounting by each client) or read-write access, but the volume *must* be mounted on the server.](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sharing%20over%20Network)

Comment: I am trying VeraCrypt at the moment. I will let you know in a few days (the encryption takes time) if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: It works. However in Ubuntu there needs to be made some special stuff to be able to mount it correctly. Windows worked fine. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871142&page=2&s=c1e9a24aaf7a9275e4a9f02b9739b8cd

Comment: And this one: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/discussions/644377

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple, elegant solution, assuming you are wanting g to do this encryption and decryption on each device.

You may be able to bodge something up by using encfs on top of a samba file share - the limitation being that encfs was not very well supported under Android (but it is partially supported - depending on the variant of Android, kernel and root ).  While there is some support for Windows I don't know how good it is.

You also want to double check that encfs is secure enough for your needs and use case.  There are always tradeoffs with using less common encryption systems and also when doing per file encryption.